# Is the power of the Shadowmasters ever ranked against the power of the Ten Who Were Taken?

Tags: black-company

The Shadowmasters and the Taken were both powerful sorcerers. I would guess that they're sort of on the same order of magnitude, since Stormbringer became a Shadowmaster, but I feel like I could be wrong. Does Glen Cook ever directly compare the power of the Taken to the power of the Shadowmasters? Was Longshadow comparable to the Dominator?

Comment: I've seen such comparison, and Shadowmasters weren't high ranked there.